# Deleting aerospike bins

Tags: nosql, aerospike

I have an Aerospike instance and I messed up one of my namespaces. I didn't know there was a ~32k limit on bins, so I wrote unique bin names into my namespace. I hit that 32k limit, and now my whole namespace is hurting. How can I delete a bin from the entire namespace so I can free up my bin limit?

I've looked at the aerospike documentation and I just can't seem to find anything. I've even looked for 3rd party programs and I can't find anything there ether.

Answer (score 4):

The data structure that maintains the bin information grows monotonically during the life of the process. The only way to remove Bin[s] from Aerospike is to first remove the bin from all records containing it followed by a rolling restart of the cluster.

You can find documentation on using scan [here](https://docs.aerospike.com/display/V3/Java+Client+-+Scan)

And see DeleteBin.java in aerospike/examples for how to delete a bin.

Answer (score 3):

You can also set the bin to null to delete it.

http://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/java/usage/kvs/write.html#delete-a-bin

Answer (score 3):

You should also delete any secondary index on that bin.